# Allow mutable values in custom dictionary to be mutated on the fly in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle, abc

I am creating custom on-disk dictionary, while trying to be as close to `dict` as possible, in terms of abilities and interface, while trying to keep interface minimal.

Currently I'm stuck with the problem that dict allows to mutate its elements, while my implementation cannot; moreover, it just swallows it.

It is not how my version is implemented, but it is a minimal example that demonstrates problem:

```py
import pickle
from pathlib import Path


class FileDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dirname = Path("filecache")
        self.dirname.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        with open(self.dirname / key, "wb") as f:
            f.write(pickle.dumps(value))

    def __getitem__(self, key: str):
        if not (self.dirname / key).exists():
            raise KeyError

        with open(self.dirname / key, "rb") as f:
            return pickle.loads(f.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = FileDict()
    c["foo"] = "bar"
    print(c["foo"])  # bar
    c["bar"] = [1, 2, 3]
    print(c["bar"])  # [1, 2, 3]
    c["bar"].append(1)
    print(c["bar"])  # [1, 2, 3] also
```

This is unexpected and unintuitive behavior (for end users; knowing implementation details this is obvious). I suspect that implementing this is hard to impossible (the only solution I see is keeping a in-memory copy of all the data and having some thread to continuously check consistency and write changes, which sounds **terrible**). Is there a way to at least fail at such attempts to let end users know that this won't work as they expect it to? If there are none, how should I inform my users about this, assuming they **won't** read the docs?

Comment: So, you are re-inventing the wheel, the standard library already has this, it's the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) module.

Comment: And there really is no good way to inform users about this if you assume they don't read the docs.

Comment: Note, even the shelve module has to deal with this, from the docs "Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable persistent-dictionary entry is modified. By default modified objects are written only when assigned to the shelf (see Example). If the optional writeback parameter is set to True, all entries accessed are also cached in memory, and written back on sync() and close(); ..."

Comment: "...this can make it handier to mutate mutable entries in the persistent dictionary, but, if many entries are accessed, it can consume vast amounts of memory for the cache, and it can make the close operation very slow since all accessed entries are written back (there is no way to determine which accessed entries are mutable, nor which ones were actually mutated)."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, I'm not. My version is using standalone database that allows concurrent writes and has other features, it is just left out of the question - it is irrelevant. `shevle` also does not support this behaviour.

Comment: Ah, alright, shevle _has_ this option and it is implemented just as I thought it can be done. Thanks, that's something.